# On click row to submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have jQuery script who is working, but i need that value from table to submit in form like club.

I need value ID to submit like club in form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("table").on('click','tr',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('value');
    alert(id);
    document.forms.league.submit('id')
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div><form method="post" name="league" action="index.php?cat=$category">
```

HTML table

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="nosort" data-sortcolumn="0" data-sortkey="0-0">Team</th>
<th class="nosort" data-sortcolumn="1" data-sortkey="1-0">Name</th>
<th class="nosort" data-sortcolumn="2" data-sortkey="2-0">Games</th>
<th class="nosort" data-sortcolumn="3" data-sortkey="3-0">Came</th>
<th class="nosort" data-sortcolumn="4" data-sortkey="4-0">Perc</th>
<th data-defaultsort="asc" class="down sorted" data-sortcolumn="5" data-sortkey="5-0">Odds<span class="sign arrow"></span></th>
<th class="nosort" data-sortcolumn="6" data-sortkey="6-0"> </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr value="Michael"><td>Michael</td>
<td>Reds</td><td>18</td><td>11</td><td>61.1%</td><td class="sorted">1.64</td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

PHP

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM results  WHERE $position='$club' order by datum desc";
```

Comment: where is `table ` class in your html code?

Comment: `tr` tags don't have a `value`. And you probably want `$("table")` not `$(".table")`

Comment: i put it in TR, that doesn't matter, i just need that value to submit form. Changed to "table" but my point is to submit that value to form, JS is working  but not submitting.

Comment: Can you edit the post? The html shown has nothing to do with the script.

Comment: You just want to submit the form? `document.forms.league.submit()`

Comment: Create a hidden text field to the form and give it a value in your script.

Comment: @squint Yes, but with the value from the table on click. So if i click on row Michael, to submit that name=Michael to form league.

Comment: It's not a big deal. Put your table codes here as well. Then we could correct the code

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small modification to your code

HTML

```
<form method="post" id="leagueForm" action="index.php"><input name="cat" type="hidden"/></form>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("table").on('click','tr',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('value');
    alert(id);
var $form = $('#leagueForm');
// set the input value
$form.find('input').val(id);

$form.submit();
});
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$submittedID = $_POST['cat'];

// Do whatever you like with the $ submittedID

?>
```

Comment: I need value of 
    val(id) to php $club. This is not posting like that, anyway i try this but it doesn't work.
Check php line upstairs

Comment: This is what this input do, put in my all empty dropmenus
( [position] => Reds [league] => Reds [limit] => Reds )
Its need to be like this
( [position] => [league] => [limit] => [club] => Reds )

Comment: I got value, but problem is all select fields has that value now too.
Array ( [position] => Reds [league] => Reds [limit] => Reds [cat] => Reds )

Comment: its a different question.. ask a different question for someones help :)

Comment: Thats my first question :)

Comment: let me clear what i said, your question was "On click row to submit", which is answered above. So the next question you are asking is jquery to PHP which is a different thing.. That's how i see it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111483/discussion-between-user3307783-and-sahan).