# Click on row to submit value from html table jquery to mysql query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm trying to get value from table and insert that value in mysql query with jQuery just to click on row. This code submit and get value from html table, but it cannot define php value $club which is needed for mysql query. So I need on click to submit that value in mysql query from html row value. 
This jquery put values in all my selects/dropmenus:

```
Array ( [position] => Reds [league] => Reds [limit] => Reds [club] => Reds )
```

Needs to be:

```
Array ( [position] =>  [league] =>  [limit] =>  [club] => Reds )
```

jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("table").on('click','tr',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr('value');
    alert(id);
var $form = $('#leagueForm');
// set the input value
$form.find('input').val(id);

$form.submit();
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" id="leagueForm" action="index.php"><input name="club" type="hidden"/></form>
```

HTML table

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="nosort" data-sortcolumn="0" data-sortkey="0-0">Team</th>
<th class="nosort" data-sortcolumn="1" data-sortkey="1-0">Name</th>
<th class="nosort" data-sortcolumn="2" data-sortkey="2-0">Games</th>
<th class="nosort" data-sortcolumn="3" data-sortkey="3-0">Came</th>
<th class="nosort" data-sortcolumn="4" data-sortkey="4-0">Perc</th>
<th data-defaultsort="asc" class="down sorted" data-sortcolumn="5" data-sortkey="5-0">Odds<span class="sign arrow"></span></th>
<th class="nosort" data-sortcolumn="6" data-sortkey="6-0"> </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr value="Reds"><td>Reds</td>
<td>Reds</td><td>18</td><td>11</td><td>61.1%</td><td class="sorted">1.64</td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

PHP submit button (before)

```
<td><button name='club' type='submit' class='btn btn-xs btn-default' value=".$row['home'].">". Click . "</button></td>
```

MySQL

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM results  WHERE $position='$club' order by datum desc";
```

Comment: can you share how you get `$club`

Comment: Before it was direct from mysql. But I want with jQuery click on the row to submit value:  <td><button name='club' type='submit' class='btn btn-xs btn-default' value=".$row['home'].">". $open . "</button></td></tr></form>

Comment: pls update the question not comment :)

Comment: And what is the problem? Question? Error?

Comment: @LoganWayne The problem is first line coded Array. Its putting value to all other input selects,dropdown menus. When I click on row needs to be just one value [club] => Reds, but it put all others [position] => Reds [league] => Reds [limit] => Reds

Comment: You have other inputs besides the hidden input (club) inside the form? Because I think you're not showing all the essential and related parts of your problem.

Comment: Yes, its related to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37119302/on-click-row-to-submit/37127333#37127333

Comment: @LoganWayne Yes, this others position, league and limit is the hidden too, but I didn't know I need to post them.

Comment: I also don't get what you want to achieve. But I guess, you want to change the arrangement/order of the data being displayed in the table by clicking something or a row, because you are only showing us a `SELECT` query.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111484/discussion-between-user3307783-and-logan-wayne).